# Finding minimum of this function

Tags: calculus

I am helping my brother with his math homework and this problem has stumped me.

I tried (150+4n)(490000/n)+0.75n as the cost function but that doesn't get me anywhere when I take second derivative.

> A company needs 490,000 items per year. It costs the company \$150 to prepare a production run of these items and \$4 to produce each item. If it also costs the company $0.75 per year for each item stored, find the number of items that should be produced in each run so that total costs of production and storage are minimized.

The correct answer is 14,000 items/run. How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Edit, sorry, mis-read the numbers.  Fixing them below.]

So if x is the number of production runs, then 490000/x is the number of items produced in a production run.  Since the cost of producing each item is the same no matter how many production runs we use, it doesn't really matter for the minimization problem.  (If you wanted to include this in the cost function, you would just add the constant value 4*490000.)  Since every production run costs 450 then that part of the cost is 150x.  And presumably we will at some point store every one of these units per production run, at a cost of (0.75)490000/x.  So the total cost function is

$150x + \frac{(0.75)\cdot 490000}{x}$

And you want to minimize this, so you take the derivative and set it to 0, then solve for x:

$150 + 0.75\cdot 490000 \cdot (-1\cdot x^{-2})=0$

so

$x^{2} = \frac{0.75\cdot 490000}{150}$

so

$x \approx 49.5$ (rejecting the negative solution as meaningless in the problem)

We then need to know the number for the lowest cost which is close to this value, so we test 49 and 50.  If you do 49 production runs then the cost is 14850 = 150*49 + 0.75*490000/49 but if you do 50 runs the cost is the same, 14850 = 150*50 + 0.75*490000/50.  So it doesn't matter which.

If you pick 49, then the number to produce is 490000/49 = 10,000.

(I see this disagrees with your teacher's result so I'll try to see if I missed anything.)

Comment: By the way, technically, since the value did not come out to an exact whole number, you should test the two nearest integers above and below.  That is to say, you ought to test the values $x=35$ and $x=36$ and choose the one that results in the lost cost.  But since the precise solution for $x$ is so close to 35, it's pretty certain that this is the right value.

Comment: For that set of parameters. Evidently the correct answer is 30,000 items/run...

Comment: I edited because it looked like I used the wrong numbers, but still not getting your teacher's result.

Comment: @Aman, I think the problem is that we're not seeing the correct numbers in the problem.  Both the other person who answered and I have used production numbers of 750,000 and so on, and now the numbers have changed.  If the production numbers really are 490,000 at $150 per production run, and 0.75 per item stored, then 49 should be the correct number of production runs, which implies 10,000 items produced in a production run.

Comment: Also, it might just be that I don't know how the production runs and storage are supposed to be used.  I am assuming that, at the start of each production run, you store all your produced units and then distribute them until the end of the production run, when you fill it back up.  And so you just pay 0.75*490000/x for storage in a year.  If that assumption is wrong, then I'm not sure what you are supposed to assume for how you pay for storage.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say a batch is $n$ items. Then you need $750000/n$ batches, so the total yearly production cost is $450 \cdot 750000/n + 4 \cdot 750000$. Each batch lasts for $n / 750000$ years, and the average number of items on storage is $n / 2$ (if the consumption rate is constant). So the total yearly cost is:
$$
450 \cdot 750000 / n + 4 \cdot 750000 + n^2 / 1500000
$$
One would probably also take it as a given that it doesn't make sense to have a batch larger than the yearly production.

Comment: Ahhh. The n/2 part was the critical portion!!